# How to mock time inside datetime in Python using unittest?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-datetime

I want to mock the `_time.time()` object that is called from the `utcnow()` method in the standard `datetime.py` library using unittest.

I have defined a mock function with `time_patch = Mock(return_value=0)` and I am trying to make the patch using `patch('datetime._time.time', wraps=time_patch).start()`.

I keep getting error `./test.py::Test1::test1 Failed with Error: module 'datetime' has no attribute '_time'`. I have checked inside the datetime.py file (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/datetime.py) and the `time` module is imported as `_time` so it should be working. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my full code:

```
import datetime
import time
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

class Test1(TestCase):

    def test1(self):

        time_patch = Mock(return_value=0)
        
        with patch('datetime._time.time', wraps=time_patch).start():

            print(time.time())

            print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

Comment: _Why_ should it be part of the `datetime` module? `import datetime; print(dir(datetime))`

Comment: I actually don't follow what you're trying to test here

Comment: @roganjosh This is just the part of the code that tries to mock `_time.time()` so I can change what `datetime.utcnow()` returns. The rest of the testing code is omitted

Comment: @deiviz - why not mock `datetime.utcnow()` directly?  Or is this a toy example of what you're trying to do with some other code you can't share?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out [freezegun](https://pypi.org/project/freezegun/)

You can set `@freeze_time("1955-11-12")` to `freeze` the time to 1955.